# clutching one's chest / at one's chest

Tags: expressions

Why is it that I'm getting overwhelmingly more results for "clutching at his chest" than for "clutching his chest"? Can you suggest any good reason? Here is an example:

> Walking again in the long corridor he felt his heart racing. He leaned on the wall **clutching at his chest**.

Here, the guy isn't really having a heart attack. Is this usage still good?

Comment: *Clutching X* usually means *grasping X firmly **in your hand***. Obviously you can't actually hold your own chest in your hand - but *to clutch **at** X* works because that conveys the sense of convulsively/eagerly *grabbing, pawing* at something (with outstretched fingers, which figuratively *would* "enclose X in the hand*, even though it's not literally possible).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: IMO, that is the answer. Please consider posting it as an answer. You can clutch a tennis ball. You can only clutch at your chest.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thx. and I'm with Drew.

Comment: @Drew: I think ELU is for people who *know* standard English. I'd have "answered" on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but here I think a comment and/or closevote are all that's required.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: OK, but see what kinds of answers *will* be posted. It seems to me that if the question is OT then it should be closed. If it is not OT then answers are appropriate here. And your comment is a good answer (IMO).

Comment: @FumbleFingers does this not qualify again? aren't you being strict? and on another note, when I clutch something, I don't expect to "enclose" it within my hand. The difference I can sense is that "clutching at" conveys a repeated attempt, and clutching is more or less grabbing, digging fingers in or something.

Comment: I think I'm just being *sensible*, not *strict*. ELL was specifically created to meet the needs of people in your situation, it being the intention that ELU should be [for linguists, etymologists, and {serious} English language enthusiasts](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @FumbleFingers So basically you're better than me? I'm translating a book, and I get it that you want me relegated to the learners division, but I don't expect to always get the same level of answers there, and I wouldn't know where's the line that separates the qualification for each question. So next time when I'm sure I'm being stupid I'll go directly to ELL. but again, I'm not sure you're in position to speak with such conviction about the proper use of ELU. that said, I do appreciate your help.

Comment: @joeav: FumbleFingers gave the right answer to your question, and now you're arguing with him instead of thanking him? Why?

Comment: @joeav: "relegated" is an emotive term to use in this context. Obviously I *know English* better than you, but that's not relevant. I don't even know if you're a native speaker or not, but if you're unaware of the (potential) distinction between *clutch* and *clutch **at***, or not familiar with commonplace usages like *clutched at his chest* that's certainly an aspect of the language you should *learn*.

Comment: @PeterShor because it's the second time since yesterday that he's answering my question, and by the way remarking that I should take my business to the learners program. In somewhat uppity tones.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you're not here to make the distinction between what's good enough to be on here and what's not, unless its categorical. I started an account here because this was where I very often ended up finding my answers, not ELL. Therefore it's more worthwhile for me to ask my questions here. I've been here two weeks, it's possible that some questions are better asked on ELL, but you're not the authority, it's not your line to draw, and you're not being nice about it. IMO, this forum can accommodate more than linguists, and you don't have to be a snob.

Comment: @joeav: I don't understand why you keep throwing around judgemental terms like "not good enough". The two sites are supposed to *serve different purposes*, but misguided prejudice like yours simply muddies the distinction and reduces the ability of *both* sites to meet the requirements of their target user base.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "I think ELU is for people who know standard English" = not good enough = snob. And if everyone who came in here "knew" your "standard English", what exactly would you have to talk about? Linguistic theory in no lay terms? Go back to school if that's what you're looking for, I'm here for work purposes and I can't be bothered with your attitude.

Comment: I'm a native English speaker from New York, and I don't find "clutch one's chest" egregious.  I'd use it interchangeably with "clutch at.."  The latter does Google better, but there are enough cites for the former that it would seem to be "in the language."  I'd more likely say "clutch one's chest," frankly.  To me, you "clutch at" something/one other than yourself.

Comment: '...  you're not here to make the distinction between what's good enough to be on here and what's not'. That's the _whole point_ of the close-voting system on this sort of website. I personally don't agree with FF on this one, but I'm totally with him when he says (paraphrasing) that ELU is not for people in their first few months of learning English (and those who appear to be). There are other sites to help with basics. This isn't a snobbish attitude; should toddlers or recent immigrants be catered for in university courses? ELU attempts to restrict questions to a non-basic level.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth so you vote it down, you don't offer your opinion on their English level saying they better go back to school. In practice, this site isn't used only by people who can phrase their questions in linguistic terms. If you wish to do so when you answer, making yourself unintelligble to the general population, that's your choice. The same question I asked here could have been phrased in linguistic terms to satisfy your need for exclusivity, but it would not necessarily contribute anything to its understanding. The fact of the matter is that you, FF, and a few other wannabe academics

Comment: ... aren't here to serve as social filters for the site by being purposefuly toxic. The site has features and algorithms for that purpose, and if they fail to achieve your desired result you should take it up with the authorities. You are no authority. You're just a guy with a problem.

Comment: Right now on stackexchange you have ELL, ELU, and the meta writers thing, and among these ELU is the more useful destination for people like me. Deal with it. If you think the only tool available to you and your group for quality controling this site is being toxic, go ahead, be toxic, for all the good it will do you. It's not going to change the makeup of the new membership coming into the site, and all you'll end up getting is an ulcer.

Comment: Collins has: **clutch** vb
1. (tr) to seize with or as if with hands or claws
2. (tr) to grasp or hold firmly
3. (usually foll by: at) to attempt to get hold or possession (of)

[Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clutch). In 'clutch/ing at his chest/heart', I'd extend the third sense to 'to attempt to relieve pain in a compressing action looking like clutching'.

Answer (score 1):

Oxford Dictionary says:

**clutch** **~ at sb/sth** to take hold of sth suddenly, because you are **afraid** or in pain

Comment: _sb/sth_ = _somebody/something_

Comment: And simply to clutch?